# CMake flag is evaluated as true, but is set to false

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake version 3.22.3 and I have the following variable set as follows:

`option(BUILD_MODULE_TEST "Option to build the module tests" OFF)`

I ran the `cmake` command with the argument `-D BUILD_MODULE_TEST:BOOL=OFF`

Running the command with trace I see the following

```
/root/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-build/CMakeLists.txt(42):  message(MT FLAG: 
${BUILD_MODULE_TEST} )
MT FLAG: OFF;BOOL;Option to build module tests
/root/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-build/CMakeLists.txt(43):  if(BUILD_MODULE_TEST )
/root/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-build/CMakeLists.txt(44):  message(Building for MT )
```

Why is the `BUILD_MODULE_TEST` variable evaluated as true?

As a remark, the variable was set previously as cache. I tried to unset the variable everywhere in CMakeLists.txt with no effect. When running `cmake` I always remove the generated files by it so as to not have any leftovers.

All these errors where observed on a WSL Ubuntu distro.

Comment: Printing `${BUILD_MODULE_TEST}` as `OFF;BOOL;Option to build module tests` is definitely **wrong**. Dereferencing an option variable should give the variable's *value* (`OFF`), not its *description*. It smells like your project **redefines** the `option` command, and its redefinition just calls `set(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked this `CMakeLists.txt` in ubuntu wsl and it works as expected:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(test)
option(BUILD_MODULE_TEST "Option to build the module tests" OFF)
message(MT FLAG: ${BUILD_MODULE_TEST})
if (BUILD_MODULE_TEST)
  message(XXX)
endif()
```

My CMake version is 3.16.3 though.

Comment: I've checked with CMake 3.23.0-rc1 and it also works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in `option()` commands are always cached. Either you remove the file `CMakeCache.txt` and folder `CMakeFiles` from the build directory or you run the configuration step in a separate build directory.

Comment: I run in a build directory the `cmake` command and remove all the contents including CMakeCache.txt each time but the variable is still evaluated as true. Using `set()` instead of `option()` has no impact, it's still the same output. Also I don't see the variable when I run `cmake -L`

Comment: As a side note, I ran the command inside a WSL Ubuntu distro. I don't know if this has any impact

Comment: What puzzles me there is the output of the `message(MT FLAG: ${BUILD_MODULE_TEST} )` command. It looks rather like a list than a variable. Do you have any other `set` command? WSL Ubuntu should not have any impact on this behaviour.